# Django. The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I'm installed my Django 1.9.2 project on CentOS 7 and get the requested URL / was not found on this server error. Log doesn't provide any nGinx error. On my PC with manage.py runserver it works.

How I installed my project on a server:

I was using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7) 
 - but I'm installed python 3.4.3 in my environment
 - created a project with project name as I have in PyCharm
 - replace project on server with my project from PyCharm via FTP

Database works (makemigration, migrate, collectstatic), site.com/admin works, I'm getting my custom 404.html page, that located in global template folder.

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*',
    ]
```

**The structure of my project is:**

[image: structure of project]

My global url:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from bakot import urls as bakot_urls
from loginsys import urls as loginsys_urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(bakot_urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', include(loginsys_urls)),
]
```

my bakot url:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from bakot import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^step(?P<step_id>[0-9]+)$', views.step, name='step'),    
    url(r'^question(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)$', views.question, name='question'),
    url(r'^newpage(?P<step_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.new_page,name='newpage'),
    url(r'^lastpage(?P<step_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.last_page,name='lastpage'),
    url(r'^answerset$', views.answerset, name='answerset'),
    url(r'^isperm$', views.isperm, name='isperm'), 

]
```

my loginsys url:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from loginsys import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^registration/', views.registration, name='registration'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

---

gunicorn:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=bakotiinii
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/bakotiinii/apifolder
ExecStart=/home/bakotiinii/apifolder/djangoen/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/bakotiinii/apifolder/apifolder.sock apifolder.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nGinx

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.ru www.example.ru;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/bakotiinii/apifolder;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/bakotiinii/apifolder/apifolder.sock;
    }
}
```

index

```
def index(request):
    stepitem = Step.objects.all()
    username = auth.get_user(request).username
    start = Step.objects.get(id = 1)
    argo = {
        "stepitem" : stepitem,
        "username" : username,
        "start" : start,
    }
    return render(request, 'bakot/index.html', argo)
```

settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*',
    ]


EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'xxx'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bakot',
    'loginsys',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'apifolder.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'apifolder.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
```

I have 2 applications in my project. bakot and loginsys, I also tried to add to my setting.py link to their templates, without any success.

```
'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bakot/templates/'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'loginsys/templates/'),            
            ]
        ,
```

Comment: What happens if you go to e.g. localhost:8000 without the /, or if you used     url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index') with a slash?

Comment: What does your nginx config look like? And how are you serving Django: gunicorn? uwsgi?

Comment: 1) With slash or without it, it get me 404 error on server, on my local PC everything is works. 2) add gunicorn and nginx settings.

Comment: Can you show the full error/traceback from the logs, and the index view?

Comment: add index view, the main problem: there is no any logs. Some guys told me, that as i use nginx as a proxy, i wouldn't have any logs.

Comment: Do you have `Append_Slash = False` in your django settings?